# Loop through MySQL and add points using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a leaderboard system for our social dart club. I have a MySQL database with players names and their points

Example:

```
Name      Date            Place        Points
John      11-01-2015      1st          10
Anthony   12-01-2015      1st          10
Andre     13-01-2015      1st          10
John      14-01-2015      1st          10
```

I need to loop through the table for each player, calculate the total points and output it leaderboard style

The top database result to

```
Name                          Points
John                          20
Andre                         10
Anthony                       10
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Your best bet here is to show some example code, even if it does not work properly.  Asking for someone else to do the work isn't going to get you far but if you show what you have tried you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, SUM(points) AS points
  FROM table1
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Build a GROUP BY and order desc by the SUM column.

Maybe you need some filter place

```
SELECT name, SUM(points) AS points
  FROM table1
WHERE place = '1st'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```